# what is the elegant way to convert the datetime to str in one element in python list？

Tags: python

I have a python list with object types as `[int, int, str, str, datetime, int]`. What is the elegant way to convert the datetime into str in the list?

The way I used which is very ugly and want to modify it:

```
import datetime

unit = {'data': [[100, 2, "65", "-9999", datetime.datetime.now(), 1312424], [99, 2, "65", "-9999", datetime.datetime.now(), 1238356]]}

idx = 0
kk = []
for dd in unit['data']:
    kk.append(unit['data'][idx][0:4] + [datetime.datetime.strftime(dd[4], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S"),] + unit['data'][idx][5:])
    idx += 1
unit['data'] = kk
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where is your data? What about a [mcve]?

Comment: Kinda hard to say without the list and the expected result, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Why are you even employing a `for` loop when you only want to do a single operation on the element with index 4?

Comment: Sorry for all enthusiasm comment and reply for my question. I revise the question description and make it more complete. As you can find the way I use is very bad. I would check the reply below and get the better implementation. Thank you again about your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one-liner way:

```
import datetime

unit["data"] = [[item.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S") if isinstance(item, datetime.datetime) else item for item in row] for row in unit["data"]]
```

As far as I'm concerned I'd wrap this in a couple utility functions though:

```
import datetime

def format_item(item):
    if isinstance(item, datetime.datetime):
        return item.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S")
    return item

def format_row(row):
    return [format_item(item) for item in row]

unit["data"] = [format_row(row) for row in unit["data"]]
```

As a side note:

1/ in your code you're using a mix of indexed access (`unit['data'][idx][0:5]` and direct item access (`dd[9]`) when you could just use  `dd` all over, ie

`dd[0:5] + (datetime.datetime.strftime(dd[9], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S"),) + dd[6:]`

2/ even if you needed indexes too, you don't have to manually maintains the current iteration index (`idx` in your code), you can just use `for index, item in enumerate(sequence):`

3/ finally, `strftime()` is  a method of `datetime.datetime`, so you can just call it directly on your  `datetime.datetime` instance, ie: `dd[9].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S")`

Comment: indeed!I have many misunderstanding of my code. That's why I mention my implement is very bad and want to find a better way to implement it. The one liner way is good for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily cast to `str` the elements in your list that match the `datetime` datatype:

```
import datetime 

now = datetime.datetime.now()

l = [1, 2, "hello", "foo", now]

for c in range(len(l)):
    if type(l[c])==datetime.datetime:
        l[c]=str(l[c])
```

Comment: Python is not C - you can iterate directly over a sequence's elements (and use `enumerate()` if you want the index too). And there's a builtin `isinstance(object, cls)` function too.